# Possibilities of an ThingSpeak Channel

Tags: web-services, http, iot, platform, data-collection

I am new to ThingSpeak and after a few hours of researching I wonder if it is possible to post pictures or data from various web pages(for example weather data from the google weather api) to a thingspeak channel?

All I found was that I would be able to visualize charts or something like that.
What I wanted to do is to collect data from various webservices(News, weather data, stock market data,..) and summarize them into the 8 channels of ThingSpeak. Is this possible? Or is there an alternative IoT platform I can use to accomplish my goal?

Thank you in advance for your answers and have a nice evening :)

Comment: Can you post some code you tried?

Comment: unfortunately not, I was just researching if it is possible to. do you have made some experiences with thingspeak?

Answer (score 1):

You can't transmit images to ThingSpeak Cloud Platform. Rather you can upload your data to Google Drive using ESP8266 or any other Wi-Fi or GSM module from your IoT device as per requirement.